# Getting twitter error in ios 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter

In iphone I add twitter framework.

When I am run that project it give me error but same project is run fine on my friend's Xcode

[image]

Comment: in your project target > build phase   add the libxml library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your project target > build phase add the libxml library

Comment: you have to make sure that your search path is correct. try $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

Answer (score 0):

You need to add lib xml header file. Follow this tutorial to know how to add lib xml frame work from [Here](http://welcome.totheinter.net/2008/03/11/adding-the-libxml-framework-to-your-iphone-app/)

go to targets-> build settings-> search for "Header search paths" and add this line "/usr/include/libxml2"

Comment: I also add path in build setting but nothing change.

Comment: then clean the project and delete the derived data and check again